# Has/have proven +

Tags: sentence-construction

Reading a book I found this sentence but cannot understand its construction. Here it is :

The media have **proven highly efficient to mold** public opinion.

Is it comparable to this one :
The media have proven high efficiency to mold public opinion. ( is this correct"

In the first sentence : **highly** is an adverb, and **efficient** is an adjective but I cannot see wich word was described by this adjective.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Highly efficient* is the complement of the verb *have proven*. *Prove*, (in this sense) like *become* and *seem* can take a noun phrase or an adjective phrase as their complement.

This is different from *prove* meaning "demonstrate that something is correct or true" - it means "turn out" or "be discovered to be". So no, your paraphrase doesn't work, because you have made *prove* transitive, and it cannot have this meaning as a transitive verb.

You could insert *to be* after *proven* without changing the meaning.